# how to add multiple aws routes to multiple aws route tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-route-table

To avoid creating multiple aws_route resources. I am trying to add multiple destination_cidr_block from a map to multiple route tables. I think I am in the right direction, however, it is only adding a **few** cidr blocks from the list to each route table and not **all** cidr blocks to each route table.

```
variable "destination_cidr_block" {
          type = map
          default = {
            destination_cidr_block = {
                 private = [
                   "0.0.0.0/0",
                   "0.0.0.0/0",
                   "0.0.0.0/0",
                   "0.0.0.0/0",]
                 private1 = [
                   "0.0.0.0/0",
                   "0.0.0.0/0"]
```

```
resource "aws_route" "private" {
  count = local.length_of_rt_cnt
  route_table_id         = element(module.private.private_route_tables_id, count.index)
  destination_cidr_block = element(var.destination_cidr_block["private1"], count.index)
  gateway_id =     module.vpc.id
}
```

How can I get all routes from private1 to the the multiple route tables that are already created from this module.

I apologize, everything has been destroyed and I did not saved the error. I know accomplishing multiple route tables with on destination cidr block which would look like this.

```
resource "aws_route" "private" {
  count = local.length_of_rt_cnt
  route_table_id         =  element(module.private.private_route_tables_id, count.index)
  destination_cidr_block = 0.0.0.0/0
  gateway_id =     module.vpc.id
}
```

In this case 4 route tables will receive this cidr block. Now the question is how can I add a list of cidr block to a list of route tables

Comment: Where is the code for the route tables?

Comment: Also, are there any errors?

Comment: it is being handled from a module and is creating multiple route tables based on the length of availability zones. So local.length_of_rt_cnt is 4. It is creating 4 route tables. How I can get ["private1] routes attached to all 4 route tables? I think my issue is the count. I think it is only looping in that list for that particular array.

Comment: Without the code added to the question, it's pretty hard to tell.

Comment: I apologize, everything has been destroyed and I did not saved the error. I know accomplishing multiple route tables with on destination cidr block which would look like this.

`resource "aws_route" "private" {
  count = local.length_of_rt_cnt
  route_table_id         = element(module.private.private_route_tables_id, count.index)
  destination_cidr_block = 0.0.0.0/0
  gateway_id =     module.vpc.id
}`

In this case 4 route tables will receive this cidr block. Now the question is how can I add a list of cidr block to a list of route tables

Comment: Add the code to the question please, not in the comment.